Gatsby build fails in docker (manual execution runs fine)
I'm trying to create a docker container for a Gatsby web app. I'm working in the GCP shell. When I do
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
gatsby clean
gatsby build

everything runs fine. But when I want o create the docker image, the build fails:
docker build -t eu.gcr.io/myproject/mycontainer .
[+] Building 321.6s (11/11) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 645B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20.17.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.2s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/node:20.17.0@sha256:48db4f6ea21d134be744207225753a1730c4bc1b4cdf836d44511c36bf0e34d7                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     5.7s
 => => transferring context: 142.58MB                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 5.6s
 => CACHED [2/7] WORKDIR /usr/src/app                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => CACHED [3/7] COPY package*.json ./                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [4/7] RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [5/7] RUN npm run clean                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [6/7] COPY . .                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   64.8s
 => ERROR [7/7] RUN npm run build                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   250.7s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 > [7/7] RUN npm run build:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
0.604                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
0.604 > myproject@1.0.0 build                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
0.604 > gatsby build                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
0.604                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
8.231 success compile gatsby files - 4.669s
success load gatsby config - 0.086s
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies is not compatible with your gatsby
8.493 version 5.13.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.24.77 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-react-i18next is not compatible with your gatsby
8.498 version 5.13.7 - It requires gatsby@^4.16.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies is not compatible with your gatsby
8.814 version 5.13.7 - It requires gatsby@^2.24.77 || ^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0
warn Plugin gatsby-plugin-react-i18next is not compatible with your gatsby
8.818 version 5.13.7 - It requires gatsby@^4.16.0
success load plugins - 0.674s
warn gatsby-plugin-react-helmet: Gatsby now has built-in support for modifying
9.174 the document head. Learn more at https://gatsby.dev/gatsby-head
success onPreInit - 0.021s
success delete worker cache from previous builds - 0.004s
success initialize cache - 0.097s
success copy gatsby files - 0.111s
success Compiling Gatsby Functions - 2.574s
success onPreBootstrap - 2.603s
success createSchemaCustomization - 0.005s
success gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: create node: en/404 - 0.018s
success gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: create node: en/common - 0.018s
success gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: create node: en/contact - 0.021s
success gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: create node: en/imprint - 0.026s
success gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: create node: en/privacypolicy - 0.030s
success gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: create node: en/index - 0.036s
success gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: create node: de/common - 0.032s
success gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: create node: de/404 - 0.037s
success gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: create node: de/contact - 0.039s
success gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: create node: de/imprint - 0.016s
success gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: create node: de/index - 0.018s
success gatsby-plugin-react-i18next: create node: de/privacypolicy - 0.012s
success Clean up stale nodes - 0.048s - 76/0 0.00/s
success Checking for changed pages - 0.001s
success source and transform nodes - 0.477s
info Writing GraphQL type definitions to /usr/src/app/.cache/schema.gql
success building schema - 0.364s
success createPages - 0.005s
success createPagesStatefully - 0.177s
info Total nodes: 128, SitePage nodes: 12 (use --verbose for breakdown)
success Checking for changed pages - 0.000s
success Cleaning up stale page-data - 0.009s
success onPreExtractQueries - 0.000s
success extract queries from components - 2.832s
success write out redirect data - 0.006s
success Build manifest and related icons - 0.345s
success onPostBootstrap - 0.352s
info bootstrap finished - 15.677s
success write out requires - 0.018s
success Building production JavaScript and CSS bundles - 91.045s
success Building HTML renderer - 23.242s
success Execute page configs - 0.116s
success Caching Webpack compilations - 0.001s
success run queries in workers - 2.144s - 15/15 7.00/s
success Running gatsby-plugin-sharp.IMAGE_PROCESSING jobs - 115.515s - 51/51
246.4 0.44/s
success Merge worker state - 0.002s
success Writing page-data.json and slice-data.json files to public directory -
246.4 0.027s - 12/12 451.38/s

249.8  ERROR  UNKNOWN
249.8 
249.8 Truncated page data information for the failed page "/de/": {
249.8   "errors": {},
249.8   "path": "/de/",
249.8   "slicesMap": {},
249.8   "pageContext": {
249.8     "language": "de",
249.8     "i18n": {
249.8       "language": "de",
249.8       "languages": [
249.8         "de",
249.8         "en"
249.8       ],
249.8       "defaultLanguage": "en",
249.8       "generateDefaultLanguagePage": false,
249.8       "routed": true,
249.8       "originalPath": "/",
249.8       "path": "de/"
249.8     }
249.8   }
249.8 }
249.8 
failed Building static HTML for pages - 3.294s

249.8  ERROR #95313  HTML.COMPILATION
249.8 
249.8 Building static HTML failed for path "/de/"
249.8 
249.8 See our docs page for more info on this error: https://gatsby.dev/debug-html
249.8 

249.9   81 |     return context[query].data
249.9   82 |   } else {
249.9 > 83 |     throw new Error(
249.9      |           ^
249.9   84 |       `The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched.\n\n` +
249.9   85 |         `This is likely a bug in Gatsby and if refreshing the page does
249.9 not fix it, ` +
249.9   86 |         `please open an issue in
249.9 https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues`
249.9 
249.9 
249.9   WebpackError: The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched.
249.9   
249.9   - static-query.js:83 
249.9     myproject/.cache/static-query.js:83:11
249.9   
249.9   - teamCards.js:12 
249.9     myproject/src/components/content/teamCards.js:12:19
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:6 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:6:2
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:8 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:8:1
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:14 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:14:1
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:17 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:17:4
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:9 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:9:1
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:14 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:14:1
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:17 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:17:4
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:16 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:16:1
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:14 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:14:1
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:17 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:17:4
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:16 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:16:1
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:14 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:14:1
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:17 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:17:4
249.9   
249.9   - AdjustmentsVerticalIcon.js:9 
249.9     [myproject]/[@heroicons]/react/20/solid/AdjustmentsVerticalIcon
249.9     .js:9:1
249.9   
249.9 
249.9 
------
Dockerfile:20
--------------------
  18 |     
  19 |     # Build the project (optional, if you have a build step)
  20 | >>> RUN npm run build
  21 |     
  22 |     # Expose the default port (optional, depends on your app)
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

As you can see here, the build fails with ERROR #95313. I search Google but there was no targeting solution for that...
This is my Dockerfile:
# Use an official Node.js image
FROM node:20.17.0

# Create a working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy the package.json and package-lock.json
COPY package*.json ./

# Install dependencies with the desired flag
RUN npm install --legacy-peer-deps

# Perform a clean build to ensure no old cache data is used
RUN npm run clean

# Copy the rest of the application
COPY . .

# Build the project (optional, if you have a build step)
RUN npm run build

# Expose the default port (optional, depends on your app)
EXPOSE 8000

# Start the application
CMD [ "npm", "start", "--", "-H", "0.0.0.0", "-p", "8080" ]

This is my package.json:
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "My Project",
  "author": "Me",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "gatsby serve",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "extract": "babel --config-file ./babel-extract.config.js -o tmp/chunk.js 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}' && rm -rf tmp",
    "format": "prettier --write 'src/**/*.{js,jsx,json,ts,tsx,md}'"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^2.1.5",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.1.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
    "axios": "^1.7.7",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "flowbite": "^2.5.1",
    "flowbite-react": "^0.10.1",
    "gatsby": "^5.13.7",
    "gatsby-plugin-breakpoints": "^1.3.6",
    "gatsby-plugin-gdpr-cookies": "^2.0.9",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^3.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^5.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-no-sourcemaps": "^5.13.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-postcss": "^6.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-preact": "^7.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-preload-fonts": "^4.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-purgecss": "^6.1.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-i18next": "^2.0.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^5.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sitemap": "^6.0.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-translate": "^1.1.5",
    "gatsby-plugin-zopfli": "^2.0.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^5.0.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^5.0.0",
    "i18next": "^23.2.11",
    "intersection-observer": "^0.12.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.6",
    "preact": "^10.6.5",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^6.0.3",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^9.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "^15.0.1",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.1.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.22"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.16.8",
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.16.8",
    "babel-plugin-i18next-extract": "^0.10.0",
    "babel-preset-gatsby": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-preset-gatsby-package": "^3.0.0",
    "postcss-import": "^16.0.0",
    "prettier": "^3.0.0",
    "pretty-quick": "^4.0.0"
  }
}

I want the creation of the image to be pass.

This question is similar to: Gatsby - The result of this StaticQuery could not be fetched. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
